# Error : Unable to prepare project

Tags: android, cordova, code-push

While trying to do a release using the following command:

```
code-push release-cordova myApp android
```

I'm getting the following error in the terminal:

> Running "cordova prepare" command: 
>   [Error]  Unable to prepare project. Please ensure that this is a Cordova  project and that platform "android" was added with "cordova platform add android"

Any one knows what might be wrong? The project is a `cordova` project created using the command:

```
cordova create myApp
```

And also has android platform added.

**UPDATE :**
Running `cordova prepare android --verbose` returns the following output :

> Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
>   Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
>   No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
>   Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
>   Wrote out Android application name to "HelloCordova"
>   Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.hellocordova"
>   This app does not have launcher icons defined
>   updated project successfully
>   Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Nodejs is the last version.
code-push-cli required "child_process"

Answer (score -1):

That error indicates that the current working directory didn't represent the root of a Cordova project at the time that you ran the release-cordova command. Can you make sure that you CD into the directory that contains the www, platforms, plugins, etc. directories, and then run the release-cordova command? That should do the trick for you